# R-how to unlist data frame list column and group by column value dynamically

Tags: r

I have data frame called df ,how to unlist dataframe column and group by column value.

my data frame.

```
CTerms        AUHistory                                                         VenDetails                                Purchaseitem     

 Valid    list(DID = c("200","300"),Dprice = c("$652.94","$252.04"))  list(`cust#`="44",CADD ="SHi,US")  list(Group="ship",Email="ga",Details= list(list(PDesc ="D,C",Bsku="47")))

 Test     list(DID = c("400","20"),Dprice = c("$252.04", "$252.04"))  list(`cust#`="45",CADD ="SHi,US")  list(Group ="ship",Email="ga",Details=list(list(PDesc ="D,C,S",Bsku="47")))

 Invalid  list(DID = c("200","200"),Dprice = c("$652.94.04","$27.4")) list(`cust#` ="44",CADD ="SHi,US") list(Group ="ship",Email="ga",Details=list(list(PDesc ="D,T",Bsku="47")))
```

Here i'm  taking cust# and checking same cust# for each row,if cust# value is same, i'm creating list with value and count for that value.For ex:cust# 44 in 1 row and 2 row is common so i'm grouping each value
    44  DID list(Value = c("200","300"),Count=c(3,1)) .Here No.Count of 200 is 3 ,300 is 2  by grouping row 1 and row 3  for common cust#44.etc.

Help me to achieve this.

My Expected Dataframe.

```
`cust#`   ColumnHeader      ColValues   

    44       CTerms          list(Value = c("Valid","Invalid"),Count=c(1,1))                              
    44       DID             list(Value = c("200","300"),Count=c(3,1))
    44       Dprice          list(Value = c("$652.94","$252.04","$652.94.04","$27.4"),Count=c(1,1,1,1))
    44       CADD            list(Value = c("SHi","US"),count=C(2,2))
    44       Group           list(Value = "ship", Count=2)
    44       Email           list(Value = "ga", Count=2)
    44       PDesc           list(Value = c("D","C","T"),Count=c(2,1,1))
    44       Bsku            list(Value = "47", Count=2)
    45       CTerms          list(Value = "Test", Count=1)
    45       DID             list(Value = c("400","20"), Count=c(1,1))
    45       Dprice          list(Value = "$252.04", Count=2)
    45       CADD            list(Value = c("SHi","US"), Count=c(1,1))
    45       Group           list(Value = "ship", Count=1)
    45       Email           list(Value = "ga", Count=1)
    45       PDesc           list(Value = c("D","C","S"),Count=c(1,1,1))
    45       Bsku            list(Value = "47", Count="1")
```

dput .

```
structure(list(CTerms = c("Valid", "Test", "Invalid"), AUHistory = list(
    structure(list(DID = c("200", "300"), Dprice = c("$652.94", 
    "$252.04")), .Names = c("DID", "Dprice"), class = "data.frame", row.names = 1:2), 
    structure(list(DID = c("400", "20"), Dprice = c("$252.04", 
    "$252.04")), .Names = c("DID", "Dprice"), class = "data.frame", row.names = 1:2), 
    structure(list(DID = c("200", "200"), Dprice = c("$652.94.04", 
    "$27.4")), .Names = c("DID", "Dprice"), class = "data.frame", row.names = 1:2)), 
    VenDetails = list(structure(list(`cust#` = "44", CADD = "SHi, US"), .Names = c("cust#", 
    "CADD"), class = "data.frame", row.names = 1L), structure(list(
        `cust#` = "45", CADD = "SHi, US"), .Names = c("cust#", 
    "CADD"), class = "data.frame", row.names = 1L), structure(list(
        `cust#` = "44", CADD = "SHi, US"), .Names = c("cust#", 
    "CADD"), class = "data.frame", row.names = 1L)), Purchaseitem = list(
        structure(list(Group = "ship", Email = "ga", Details = list(
            structure(list(PDesc = "D, C", Bsku = "47"), .Names = c("PDesc", 
            "Bsku"), class = "data.frame", row.names = 1L))), .Names = c("Group", 
        "Email", "Details"), class = "data.frame", row.names = 1L), 
        structure(list(Group = "ship", Email = "ga", Details = list(
            structure(list(PDesc = "D, C, S", Bsku = "47"), .Names = c("PDesc", 
            "Bsku"), class = "data.frame", row.names = 1L))), .Names = c("Group", 
        "Email", "Details"), class = "data.frame", row.names = 1L), 
        structure(list(Group = "ship", Email = "ga", Details = list(
            structure(list(PDesc = "D, T", Bsku = "47"), .Names = c("PDesc", 
            "Bsku"), class = "data.frame", row.names = 1L))), .Names = c("Group", 
        "Email", "Details"), class = "data.frame", row.names = 1L))), .Names = c("CTerms", 
"AUHistory", "VenDetails", "Purchaseitem"), row.names = c(NA, 
3L), class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: What have you tried so far? There is some work to get there. Seems you haven't started yourself?

Comment: Hi Rockbar, yes i was . Is their any way to achieve my post. I tried many ways but don't.

Comment: please any one help me above my post is possible or not, if possible means how to achieve.

Comment: You should at least attempt to find your own way through this challenge. Nobody here will write you the complete code and do the work for you.

Comment: @Rockbar.Yes u'r Right,same time i'm new for R programming language couple of weeks .Even thought till now i tried my best and  i will .But the problem is i have short time to finish my task that's why i'm asking help from Experts.